# Bootstrap 4 center image but text left aligned

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap 4 and I have row like this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Row -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4">
          <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/10/15/18/32/bee-eaters-3749679_960_720.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
          <p>My First Text</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4">
          <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/04/04/12/34/sunset-100367_960_720.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
          <p>My Second Text</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4">
          <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_960_720.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
          <p>My Third Text</p>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

This works fine - but as soon as I decrease the browser size I have the images among themselves which is also expected. Nevertheless the images are now left aligned. So in the mobile view I want the images also horizontal centered but the corresponding text left aligned. When I add the "text-center" to the columns, the images are horizontal center but the text as well. So how can I center the image but leave the text left aligned to the left side of the image?

Comment: Easiest of way doing this is to put the image and text in a col as well. Just offset the image to be centered

Comment: @SuperDJ Can you provide an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `text-center`, use `mx-auto d-block` on the images...

```
<img src="..." alt="" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block">
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/UU1RXLwRUE

Comment: The image is centered with this approach but the text should be left aligned with the image. Any ideas?

Comment: Put the image and text together in a div like this: https://www.codeply.com/go/nz4Ta9ulwQ -- Use `d-flex` on the columns and `mx-auto` to center the inner div.